# Automapper rule for custom property type

Tags: c#, automapper

So I have this class TranslatedString : ListDictionary

```
public class TranslatedString {
    public string Language {get;set}

    public string Value {
        get {
            return this[Language] as string;
        }
        set {
            this[Language] = value;
        }
    }
    ....more complex logic in this class
}
```

and a destination class that looks like this:

```
{
    public TranslatedString Name {get;set;}
    public TranslatedString Desc {get;set;}

    public void SetLanguage(string lang) {
       this.Name.Language = lang;
       this.Desc.Language = lang;
    }
}
```

Now I want to map a source like this to the destination above:

```
{
    public string Language {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
}
```

Here's my map:

```
CreateMap<String, TranslatedString>(MemberList.None)
  .ForMember(x => x.Value, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));

CreateMap<Source, Dest>(MemberList.Source)
  .BeforeMap((s, d, context) {
      d.SetLanguage((string)context.Items["Language"]);
  });
```

and here's how I map:

```
var dest = Mapper.Map<Dest>(source, opt => opt.Items["Language"] = "en");
```

The issue I have is that when automapper maps string => TranslatedString it creates a new instance of each TranslatedString which means that "Language" which is set in "BeforeMap" looses it's value. How can solve this and keep a common solution for all String => TranslatedString mappings for all classes?

Comment: Did you try AfterMap?

Comment: I edited the TranslatedString class which probably explains why AfterMap won't help. The language must be set before the other properties are set.

Comment: Then ignore that property you're setting in BeforeMap.